# Count only active records for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

I have create a temporary table of 'tasks', called `#CFTasks` that looks like this:

```
ID           STARTDATE    ENDDATE
1712060019   06/12/2017   07/12/2017
1712060019   07/12/2017   07/12/2017
1712060019   08/12/2017   08/12/2017
1712060019   07/12/2017   08/12/2017
1712060019   07/12/2017   12/12/2017
1712060019   12/12/2017   13/12/2017
1712060019   14/12/2017   14/12/2017
1712060019   07/12/2017   14/12/2017
1712060019   14/12/2017   NULL
1712060019   07/12/2017   14/12/2017
1712060019   18/12/2017   21/12/2017
1712060019   18/12/2017   21/12/2017
1712060019   19/12/2017   21/12/2017
1712060019   02/11/2018   24/09/2018
1712060019   14/09/2018   24/09/2018
1712060019   13/10/2018   05/12/2018
1712060019   13/10/2018   05/12/2018
1712060019   12/11/2018   05/12/2018
1712060019   19/12/2018   07/12/2018
1712060019   13/12/2018   07/12/2018
```

For each month from the 1st December 2017 to the current month, I want to know how many of these records were active, by which I mean the `[STARTDATE]` is less than or equal to the first of the month and the `[ENDDATE]` is greater than the first of the month or the `[ENDDATE]` is NULL

i.e.

`[DUEDATE] <= @StartOfMonth
 AND (    [ENDDATE] >= @StartOfMonth
           OR [ENDDATE] IS NULL
     )`

For the sample task table provided, I'd expect the output to look like:

```
Month        ActiveTasks
01/12/2017   0
01/01/2018   1
01/02/2018   1
01/03/2018   1
01/04/2018   1
01/05/2018   1
01/06/2018   1
01/07/2018   1
01/08/2018   1
01/09/2018   1
01/10/2018   1
01/11/2018   3
01/12/2018   4
```

I've created a date table too, so that I can get a count even where there are no active tasks on a particular reporting date but I can't find a way to join the two tables in such a way that I get the desired result.

My date table is created like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CalendarMonths
DECLARE @StartDate  date 
SELECT @StartDate = '20171201';

DECLARE @CutoffDate date = getdate()

;WITH seq(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
  WHERE n < DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)
),
m(m) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, @StartDate) FROM seq
)
SELECT m AS [Month]
INTO #CalendarMonths
FROM m
ORDER BY m
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

I've tried joining the two tables in every way I can think of but I'm always stuck with the fact that I don't actually want to group the output by the `[STARTDATE]` or `[ENDDATE]` but rather by the reporting date and the fact that I want NULLs to be considered active from the start date onward.

The closest I've managed to get (meaning the query doesn't simply fail) is the below. The problem is I know I'm going down a blind alley and that this approach just won't work, no matter how much I tweak it but I just can't construct the problem in a way my brain can solve it in SQL. In Excel the same task would take me a couple of minutes but I'm working with over 600,000 rows and Excel just isn't the right tool for the job.

```
SELECT cm.[Month],
       COUNT(cft.ID) AS TasksDue
FROM #CalendarMonths cm
LEFT JOIN #CFTasks cft ON cft.STARTDATE <= cm.[Month]
                       AND cft.ENDDATE > cm.[Month]
GROUP BY cm.[Month]
ORDER BY cm.[Month]
```

Comment: Your query looks correct to me.

Comment: What about when the `ENDDATE` is NULL?

Comment: Pasting sample data as as text is far more useful than an image

Comment: @JohnCappelletti is that better?

Comment: @MLucas Much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support a `NULL` end date, then you just need to tweak your query:

```
SELECT cm.[Month],
       COUNT(cft.ID) AS TasksDue
FROM #CalendarMonths cm LEFT JOIN
     #CFTasks cft
     ON cft.STARTDATE <= cm.[Month] AND
        ( cft.ENDDATE > cm.[Month] OR cft.ENDDATE IS NULL )
GROUP BY cm.[Month]
ORDER BY cm.[Month];
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is absolutely correct, and infuriatingly I'd already tried it myself before posting. Sadly, when I checked the results for a given month against another existing query the two outputs didn't match, it turns out my new one wasn't the problem!